# How to add an "Attribute" using Schema Workbench?

Tags: pentaho, mondrian

For educational reasons I would like to reproduce the following example schema from "Mondrian in Action":

[image]

But I cannot find a button for "Add Attribute"!?

[image]

I am only offered buttons for:

- add cube
- add dimension
- add dimension usage
- add hierarchy
- add named set
- add user defined function
- add calculated member
- add measure
- add level
- add property
- add calculated member property
- add virtual cube
- add virtual cube dimension
- add virtual cube measure
- add role

Why is "add attribute" missing? Or ... what is it that I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"attribute" has been added to Mondrian schema at version 4 while the Schema Workbench is officially [no longer maintained](http://diethardsteiner.blogspot.mx/2013/01/mondrian-4-get-ready.html) and stuck at Mondrian schema version 3.x.

This should be the documentation for Mondrian 4:

http://mondrian.pentaho.com/head/documentation/schema.php

And this "seems" to be an older version - maybe 3.x:

http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php